# existing express app and chat with socket.io

Tags: express, socket.io

I try to add a chat feature to my express app. to allow users to write instant messages to each other. I already built the express app. I built also a separate socket.io app. 
What I don't know, is how to connect them? 
In practice, I need to allow only authenticated users in my express ap to use the chat app.

I tried to pass a server instance to the chat app but it doesn't work. Routing from main app to chat app also. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can register a middleware for authentication.

```
const socketIo =  require('socket.io');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

const io = socketIo(server);
// use io middleware for socket connection authentication
io.use( function (socket, next){
   //do authentication stuff here
   next();
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
   //Handle Socket Events here
});
```

Please see https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-use-fn